# Is there a clean way to get the n-th column of an html table using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table

Say we look at the first table in a page, so:

```
table = BeautifulSoup(...).table
```

the rows can be scanned with a clean for-loop:

```
for row in table:
    f(row)
```

But for getting a single column things get messy.

My question: is there an elegant way to extract a single column, either by its position, or by its 'name' (i.e. text that appears in the first row of this column)?

Answer (score 5):

[lxml](http://lxml.de) is many times faster than BeautifulSoup, so you might want to use that.

```
from lxml.html import parse
doc = parse('http://python.org').getroot()
for row in doc.cssselect('table > tr'):
    for cell in row.cssselect('td:nth-child(3)'):
         print cell.text_content()
```

Or, instead of looping:

```
rows = [ row for row in doc.cssselect('table > tr') ]
cells = [ cell.text_content() for cell in rows.cssselect('td:nth-child(3)') ]
print cells
```