# How to get first child table row from a table in BeautifulSoup ( Python )

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Here is the Code and sample results , I just want the first column of the table ignoring the rest. There are similar question on Stackoverflow but they did not help.

```
<tr>
<td>JOHNSON</td>
<td> 2,014,470 </td>
<td>0.81</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
```

I want JOHNSON only, as it is the first child.
My python code is :

```
import requests
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 def find_raw():
      url = 'http://names.mongabay.com/most_common_surnames.htm'
      r = requests.get(url)
      html = r.content
      soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
      for n in soup.find_all('tr'):
          print n.text
  
  find_raw()
```

What I get:

```
SMITH 2,501,922 1.0061
JOHNSON 2,014,470 0.812
```

Comment: Your question is not totally clear. If you get the first child td for each tr, you want the first *column* not the first *row*. Can you clarify?

Comment: edited. it is the column indeed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find all the `tr` tags with `find_all`, then for each `tr` you `find` (gives only the first) `td`. If it exists, you print it:

```
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    td = tr.find('td')
    if td:
        print td
```

Comment: Thank You , Could you explain it ? I mean what if I need to iterate only second or third row ?

Answer (score 3):

Iter through tr, then print text of first td:

```
for tr in bs4.BeautifulSoup(data).select('tr'):
    try:
        print tr.select('td')[0].text
    except:
        pass
```

Or shorter:

```
>>> [tr.td for tr in bs4.BeautifulSoup(data).select('tr') if tr.td]
[<td>SMITH</td>, <td>JOHNSON</td>, <td>WILLIAMS</td>, <td>JONES</td>, ...]
```

Related posts:

- [Is there a clean way to get the n-th column of an html table using BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532307/is-there-a-clean-way-to-get-the-n-th-column-of-an-html-table-using-beautifulsoup)
- [Extracting selected columns from a table using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074586/extracting-selected-columns-from-a-table-using-beautifulsoup)
- [CSS select with beautifulsoup4 doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603502/css-select-with-beautifulsoup4-doesnt-work/22603756#22603756)
- [Python BeautifulSoup Getting a column from table - IndexError List index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494085/python-beautifulsoup-getting-a-column-from-table-indexerror-list-index-out-of)
- [BeautifulSoup Specify table column by number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973680/beautifulsoup-specify-table-column-by-number)